# skype does not see logitech pro 9000 - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video, skype

This camera works fine with cheese, but while it appears as the USB device skype recognizes, there is no video shown.

[This post](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-webcam-problem-in-skype.html)  and others mention libv4l-0.

`apt-get install libv4l-0` reports that the latest version is already installed.

The closest I can find to what is mentioned in that post are:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

and

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0
```

In both cases when I try to `LD_PRELOAD` these I get something like `object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored`

and skype still does not see the camera correctly.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: the link says: "To fix this you need to have libv4l-0 installed and load it with Skype.", so have you changed *.desktop* file to load with **libv4l-0** ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the .desktop file and also tried from the command line with the same results. However, It finally seems to working this morning. Perhaps it needed a cold reboot(?), although having spent too many years with Windows I of course did try restarting after making changes. Actually, I should say that I can now see video in the skype options - I have not yet actually made a call.

Comment: ok, then make sure that this worked and post it as answer, and after ~2 hours you can accept it. :)

Comment: I have successfully made an outgoing video call, so skype is recognizing the camera. When I get an incoming call skype rings then immediately dies. I'm thinking this is a distinct issue, not related to the camera. Interestingly, I now have the same results whether the .desktop file simply has the original "exec=skype %U" or if it includes the preload instruction.